# Gradle: disable UP-TO-DATE check since build.grade is changed

Tags: gradle

Gradle: how to disable UP-TO-DATE check since build.grade is changed?

```
gradle taskFoo --disable-up-to-date-check
```

build.gradle is changed, but gradle still thinks all tasks UP-TO_DATE by checking inputs and outputs hash.

Clean task for cleaning build directory only. These files generated by the build task are in source control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `gradle taskFoo --rerun-tasks`. This will force tasks to run again even when they are up-to-date.